# extract soap body with http 400 code

Tags: java, soap, javax

Following java code throws exception when the Http results is in > 400 range.
Using javax library

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction, operatorid, publicnodeid, devicetype),
                soapEndpointUrl);

        // Print the SOAP Response
        System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        soapConnection.close();
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        System.err.println(
                "\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("the error stack is" + e.getCause());

    }
```

In my actual response there is a faultcode and faulttype and i want the actual response body to be captured so that further information get extracted from the SOAP response body.
How can i get the response body ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the exception is thrown at `soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);`, `writeTo()` will throw SOAPException if there was a problem in externalizing this SOAP message. You should check SOAPHeader or SOAPBody before use the SOAPMessage, find the code and do some action with different codes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but it is not thrown by soapResponse.writeTo(System.out). As per the debug logs exception thrown by soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction, operatorid, publicnodeid, devicetype),
                soapEndpointUrl);

Comment: Ok, please add the exception log